# how can we check the current SharePoint Installation type?

Tags: installation, configuration, server-farm

how can we check the installation type of a SharePoint server if it's Farm or Standalone
/Foundation or MOSS

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same information, and just found the answer [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010setup/thread/6fee8444-1661-47fb-bb26-16a80d18dac8).

Here are the steps:

1. Launch regedit.exe
2. For MOSS 2007, navigate to:
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0\WSS
3. For Sharepoint 2010, navigate to:
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS
4. Check the **ServerRole** key

Here are the valid values:

- SINGLESERVER => Stand Alone
- APPLICATION => Farm Complete
- WFE => Web Front End

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/05/how-to-reliably-detect-moss-or-wss-at.html

```
/// <summary> 
/// Method to find out if a SharePoint installation is MOSS or WSS 3.0 
/// </summary> 
public static bool IsMOSS() 
{ 
    SPFeatureDefinitionCollection features = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Farm.FeatureDefinitions; 
    if (features["OssNavigation"] != null && features["Publishing"] != null) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean in code

Comment: Maybe you should mention that in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Central Administration > Manage servers in this farm (under System Settings)

**Configuration database version** of 14.xxx is 2010 and 12.xxx is 2007

**SharePoint Products Installed** will show you the product.

Comment: this doesn't show if it's a farm or Standalone installation

Comment: If is was installed as standalone, a database instance servername\sharepoint would have been created for SQL Server Express. You could check if that exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the installation type by going to regedit and navigate to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\

[image]

Comment: Where does it say it's farm or standalone installation?

Answer (score -1):

Different people use different technique. It appears that you are absolute beginner so I will try to keep it as simple as possible.

Check following location

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions

If you see 12 folders, you have WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007. If you have “14” folder, you have SharePoint Foundation or Sharepoint Server 2010.

Check ISAPI folder under “12” or “14” folder, if you find assemblies like Microsoft.Office.Server or Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, you have full SharePoint Server (MOSS or 2010) and not WSS 3.0 or SharePoint Foundation 2010